# ASP.NET Core Web API : add non-CRUD opperations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Is it possible to add non-Crud operations such as deleting a file in a Web API? For example, after a `GetByID`, this method deletes a file:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Issue), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id)
{
    var issue = await _context.Issues.FindAsync(id);

    DeleteFiles("C:\New\amit.txt");

    return issue == null ? NotFound() : Ok(issue);
}
```

The `DeleteFile` method is:

```
public DeleteFile(string mypath) 
{
    if (File.Exists(myPath))
    {
        // If file found, delete it    
        File.Delete(myPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Deleting a file is a CRUD operation (Create, Read, Update, Delete)... You should never modify server objects in a GET route. Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: Of course you can *do* it, technically - but I would ***never*** expect a `GET` method to modify state or delete a file or anything like that! This goes against **all** conventions and expectations of your API's users ..... think really hard about this - it violates the "Principle of Least Surprise", for sure!